# Python int object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, collision-detection, separating-axis-theorem

I'm currently trying to implement my own SAT (separating axis theorem) collision detection system but have run into an issue. On line 34 I'm getting this error message:

> line 34, in collision
>      axis = (v[1], -v[0])
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

The weird thing is that v is not an int, it's a tuple.

Here's the code

```
import math
import pygame

WIDTH = 900
HEIGHT = 700

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def dot(v1, v2):
    return v1[0]*v2[0] + v1[1]*v2[1]

polygons = []

class Polygon():
    def __init__(self, points):
        self.points = points
        self.vectors = []
        for p1 in range(len(self.points)):
            p2 = p1 + 1
            if p2 > len(self.points) - 1:
                p2 = 0
            v = (self.points[p2][0] - self.points[p1][0], self.points[p2][1] - self.points[p1][1])#int object not subscriptable
            self.vectors.append(v)
        polygons.append(self)
    def collision(self):
        for p in polygons:
            collision = True
            if p.points != self.points:
                for v in range(len(p.vectors)):
                    axis = (v[1], -v[0])
                    selfFirst = True
                    pFirst = True
                    for point in self.points:
                        if selfFirst == True:
                            selfFirst = False
                            projection = dot(point, axis)
                            selfMin = projection
                            selfMax = projection
                        else:
                            projection = dot(point, axis)
                            if projection < selfMin:
                                selfMin = projection
                            elif projection > selfMax:
                                selfMax = projection
                    for point in p.points:
                        if pFirst == True:
                            pFirst = False
                            projection = dot(point, axis)
                            pMin = projection
                            pMax = projection
                        else:
                            projection = dot(point, axis)
                            if projection < pMin:
                                pMin = projection
                            elif projection > pMax:
                                pMax = projection
                    if (selfMin > pMin and selfMin < pMax) or (selfMax > pMin and selfMax < pMax):
                        collision = True
                    else:
                        collision = False
                        return collision

polygon1 = Polygon([(0, 0), (100, 100), (0, 100)])
polygon2 = Polygon([(300, 300), (150, 0), (0, 150)])

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.fill((0,0,0))

for polygon in polygons:
    polygon.collision()
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, (0, 255, 0), polygon.points, 1)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)


    pygame.display.quit()
```

The problem is on line 34

Comment: for v in range(len(p.vectors)): this is a list of int's the v you are looking at is an int

Comment: which line is 34 ?

Comment: in `v` you have number - ie. `123` - so you try to do `axis = (123[1], -123[0])`. Maybe you need `axis = (p.vectors[v][1], -p.vectors[v][0])`

Comment: Okay, I fixed that part, getting some bugs elsewhere but I'll try to fix those myself. thanks. Should I close this down or what? this is my first post.

Comment: Hey, I would really appreciate if you could validate my answer, if it was useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So the `v` inside your loop is an integer, and it doesnt make sense to access to the first/second position of an integer (thats what you do when the `v[1], -v[0]` thing) hence you get that error about subscriptable things.

In:

```
for v in range(len(p.vectors)):
        axis = (v[1], -v[0])
```

the `range` returns a list of integers, because you passed another integer as parameter to it (`len(p.vectors)`). Don't really know what `p.vectors` is, I assume is a list of obects `v` that may have positions `0` and `1` on them, so then maybe this will work:

```
for v in p.vectors:
        axis = (v[1], -v[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an object lesson in variable naming.

In line 27 you assign `v` in `__init__()` to:
`v = (self.points[p2][0] - self.points[p1][0], self.points[p2][1] - self.points[p1][1])`

Then in the loop you reassign it and clobber you previous assignment:
`for v in range(len(p.vectors)):`

`len()` returns an integer and `range()` returns a list of integers. So with each loop `v` is assigned an integer from that range. Hence `v` is now an integer and not subscriptable.

Maybe something like:
`for v in p.vectors:` would work better for you.